# Predicting KNN and using in McNemar

Tags: r, prediction, knn

I am trying to use McNemar on three different algorithms (knn, Decision Trees and Naive Bayes). While writting my code I am stumbling on a few problems in predicting KNN. It seems the knnPrediction function (below) receives NA strings or the lenght is not the same? I have very little experience in KNN, and I searched everywhere for an answer but could not resolve my problem. Does anybody have an idea? (scroll down to the end to "cl <- trainData[,ncol(trainData)]")
I tried thia different line too:
cl <- as.formula(paste(variableCible,"~.")
without results.

```
runAnalysis <- function(fileName,separator=","){

  nastrings <- c(NA, " ?", "?", "NA", " NA")

  #load raw data
  rawData <- read.table(
    file=fileName,
    header=TRUE,
    sep=separator,
    na.strings = nastrings)
  donneesBrutes <- na.omit(rawData)
  variableCible <-names(donneesBrutes)[length(donneesBrutes)]

  library(rpart)
  library(e1071)
  source("knn.R")


  #On fixe nos données aléatoire 
  set.seed(1)
  #Nombre du découpage pour le test de précision et les erreurs
  V <- 5
  #Nombre d'occurence dans nos données
  nbOccurence <-nrow(donneesBrutes)
  #Tableau des différents parties
  taille <- nbOccurence %/% V
  #Mélange des données pour éviter les tri
  donneesBrutes <- donneesBrutes[as.factor(sample(rownames(donneesBrutes))),]
  arbreDecisionPredictions<-c()
  arbreDecisionPrecisions<-c()
  naivesBayesPrecisions<-c()
  naivesBayesPredictions<-c()
  knnPredictions <- c()
  knnPrecisions <- c()
  classifieurParDefaut <- CPD(donneesBrutes)
  for (v in 1:(V-1)){
    testIndex <- ((v - 1) * taille + 1):(v * taille)
    trainData <- donneesBrutes[-testIndex,]
    testData <- donneesBrutes[testIndex,]
    #Arbre de décision
    arbreDecisionP <- arbreDecisionPrediction(trainData, testData, variableCible)
    arbreDecisionPrecisions <- c(arbreDecisionPrecisions, precision(arbreDecisionP,testData))
    arbreDecisionPredictions <- c(arbreDecisionPredictions, arbreDecisionP)
    #Naives Bayes
    naivesBayesP <- naivesBayesPrediction(trainData, testData,variableCible)
    naivesBayesPrecisions <- c(naivesBayesPrecisions, precision(naivesBayesP,testData))
    naivesBayesPredictions <- c(naivesBayesPredictions, naivesBayesP)
    #Knn
    knnP <- knnPrediction(trainData, testData, variableCible)
    knnPrecisions <- c(knnPrecisions, precision(knnP, testData))
    knnPredictions <- c(knnPredictions, knnP)
  }
  #Pour avoir des parties de taille égal
  testIndex <- ((V - 1) * taille + 1):(dim(donneesBrutes)[1])
  trainData <- donneesBrutes[-testIndex,]
  testData <- donneesBrutes[testIndex,]
  #Arbre de décision
  arbreDecisionP <- arbreDecisionPrediction(trainData, testData,variableCible)
  arbreDecisionPrecisions <- c(arbreDecisionPrecisions, precision(arbreDecisionP,testData))
  arbreDecisionPredictions <- c(arbreDecisionPredictions, arbreDecisionP)
  #Naives Bayes
  naivesBayesP <- naivesBayesPrediction(trainData, testData,variableCible)
  naivesBayesPrecisions <- c(naivesBayesPrecisions, precision(naivesBayesP,testData))
  naivesBayesPredictions <- c(naivesBayesPredictions, naivesBayesP)
  #Knn
  knnP <- knnPrediction(trainData, testData, variableCible)
  knnPrecisions <- c(knnPrecisions, precision(knnP, testData))
  knnPredictions <- c(knnPredictions, knnP)

  print("Précision des algorithmes : Arbre de décision, Naives Bayes et Classifieur par défaut")
  print(paste("Arbre de décision :", precision(arbreDecisionPredictions,donneesBrutes)))
  #print(arbreDecisionPrecisions)
  print(paste("Naives Bayes :", precision(naivesBayesPredictions,donneesBrutes)))
  #print(naivesBayesPrecisions)
  print(paste("Classifieur par défaut :", precision(classifieurParDefaut,donneesBrutes)))
  #print(knnPrecision)
  print(paste("KNN : ", precision(knnPredictions, donneesBrutes)))

  print("")

  print("Comparaison des algorithmes avec McNemar")
  #Arbre de décision et Naives Bayes
  m<-mcNemar(arbreDecisionPredictions,naivesBayesPredictions)
  print(paste("Arbre de décision et Naives Bayes", mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
  #Arbre de décision et Classifieur par défaut
  m<-mcNemar(arbreDecisionPredictions,classifieurParDefaut)
  print(paste("Arbre de décision et Classifieur par défaut",mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
  #Classifieur par défaut et Naives Bayes
  m<-mcNemar(naivesBayesPredictions,classifieurParDefaut)
  print(paste("Classifieur par défaut et Naives Bayes",mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
  #Arbre de décision et KNN
  m<-mcNemar(arbreDecisionPredictions,knnPredictions)
  print(paste("Arbre de décision et KNN", mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
  #Naive et KNN
  m<-mcNemar(naivesBayesPredictions,knnPredictions)
  print(paste("Naive bayes et KNN", mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
  #Classifieur par défaut et KNN
  m<-mcNemar(knnPredictions,classifieurParDefaut)
  print(paste("Classifieur par défaut et KNN",mcnemar.test(m)$p.value))
  print(m)
}

#Fonction pour récupérer la comparaison entre deux algo
mcNemar <- function (predictionsA, predictionsB){
  FauxFaux <- length(which(predictionsA==FALSE & predictionsB==FALSE))
  FauxVrai <- length(which(predictionsA==FALSE & predictionsB==TRUE))  
  VraiFaux <- length(which(predictionsA==TRUE & predictionsB==FALSE))
  VraiVrai <- length(which(predictionsA==TRUE & predictionsB==TRUE))
  m <- matrix(c(FauxFaux, FauxVrai, VraiFaux, VraiVrai), nrow=2, dimnames=list("Algorithmes B" = c("#wrong", "#correct"), "Algorithmes A" = c("#wrong", "#correct")))
  m
}

#Fonction pour récupérerles prédictions d'un arbre de décision
arbreDecisionPrediction <- function (trainData, testData, variableCible){
  testDataNoLab <- testData[,1:ncol(testData)-1]
  #Création de l'arbre
  arbre<-rpart(as.formula(paste(variableCible,"~.")), data=trainData, minsplit=80,cp=0.01,parms=list(split="gini"))
  #Prédictions avec les données de test
  predictions <- predict(arbre, testDataNoLab, type="class")    
  #Calcul et retour des résultats
  predictions==testData[,ncol(testData)]
}

#Fonction pour récupérer la précision 
precision <- function(model, testData){
  #Récupére la longueur de la valeur correct
  numCorrect<-length(which(model))
  #Récupére la précision en %
  numCorrect/dim(testData)[1]
}

#Fonction pour récupérerles prédictions d'un model de naives bayes
naivesBayesPrediction <- function (trainData, testData, variableCible){
  testDataNoLab <- testData[,1:ncol(testData)-1]
  #Création du modele de naives bayes
  naivesBayesModel<-naiveBayes(as.formula(paste(variableCible,"~.")),trainData)
  #Prédictions avec les données de test
  predictions <- predict(naivesBayesModel, testDataNoLab, type="class")  
  #Calcul et retour des résultats
  predictions==testData[,dim(testData)[2]]
}

#Fonction pour récupérer les predictions de KNN
knnPrediction <- function(trainData, testData, variableCible){
  testDataNoLab <- testData[,1:ncol(testData)-1]
  print(trainData[,ncol(trainData)])

  cl <- trainData[,ncol(trainData)] ------------------------ Here seems to be the problem
  knnModel <-knn(trainData,testData, cl)
  #Prédictions avec les données de test
  predictions <- predict(knnModel, testDataNoLab, type="class")  
  #Calcul et retour des résultats
  predictions==testData[,dim(testData)[2]]
}

#Fonction pour récupérerles prédictions du classifieur par défaut
CPD <- function (data){  
  cpd <- sort(table(data[,ncol(data)]))
  data[,ncol(data)]==names(cpd[length(cpd)])
}
```

Comment: I want to help, but there is no demo-data in your code, so I can't reproduce anything. Also I don't understand your comments in the code. Maybe you could create a reduced/simplified version of your code that I can run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Tobi
Sorry, maybe I wasn't very clear. I am using the "adult" [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult) dataset. I would like to use the McNemar's test to chose the best algorithm out of KNN, Naive Bayes and Decision Trees. My code is working for everything except for KNN (it prints the accuracy, precision and McNemar ). My problem is when I want to predict to gather the precision in these lines:
knnP <- knnPrediction(trainData, testData, variableCible)
knnPrecisions <- c(knnPrecisions, precision(knnP, testData))

error is: "NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: @Tobi Stackoverflow restricts the number of characters, so it is difficult for me to post a new code smaller than the one I put. But basically, in my knnPrediction function, the "cl" attribute is returning errors because it doesn't understand my class labels "<=50K" and ">50K" even though I try to factor it